# What is the quantum mechanical explanation of the Mass–energy equivalence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

What is the quantum or particle explanation of the equivalence between mass and energy described by Einstein? What mechanisms ensure this equivalence?

Comment: why should there be a quantum explanation to this more than an quand tum explanation for the form of the kinetic energy as $p^2/2m$?

Comment: The correct quantum theories incorporate in the mathematics Lorentz transformations , and the theories describe the data and observations and are predictive, thus the incorporation is justified.

Comment: Mass is rest-energy divided by $c^2$, by definition. Definitions are just definitions, not something to be explained. Are you really asking why the relationship between energy and momentum (for a free particle) has the form $E^2-(pc)^2=\text{constant}$? The answer to that question would be Lorentz symmetry, combined with the definitions of energy and momentum as the conserved quantities associated with time-translation and space-translation symmetry, respectively. Relativistic quantum field theory uses those same definitions / symmetries, so it doesn't add anything new to the explanation.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly and of course QM has nothing to do with this. It is a purely relativistic phenomenon. It isn't incompatible with QM, but there's nothing in QM that requires it to be true, in fact, QM can be applied to nonrelativistic systems where it is not true.